# TextField disappear when mouse leave

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

When I take off the mousepointer from the textfield it is disappearing..i tried the following code..which does add an attribute called visibility and setting the value to 'visible'..but it did not work either..

Please help me to solve my problem..

CODE :

```
jq("#meteringpointtable").find(".search.results.field.point").mouseleave(function(){
     jq("#meteringpointtable .search.results.field.point").attr('visibility','visible');`enter code here`
});
```

NEW CODE :

```
   jq("#meteringpointtable").find(".search.results.field.point").mouseleave(functio‌​‌​n(){
     jq(this).css({'visibility':'visible'}); 
     console.log(jq(this).css('visibility')); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility) is a css property so you should use it this way.

Also it seems like you are using the same selector while attaching the event. SO you can refer to that element with `this` (DOMElement) /`$(this)` (Jquery object).

```
jq("#meteringpointtable").find(".search.results.field.point").mouseleave(function(){
     jq(this).css({'visibility':'visible'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..but it did not work.. t make sure..i tried..



 jq("#meteringpointtable").find(".search.results.field.point").mouseleave(function(){
    jq(this).css({'visibility':'visible'});
    console.log(jq(this).css('visibility'));
});

it prints the value 'visible' but it still disappears..

Comment: post your html section which doesn't work.. Can you put it in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: jq("#meteringpointtable").find(".search.results.field.point").mouseleave(functio‌​n(){
   jq(this).css({'visibility':'visible'});      console.log(jq(this).css('visibility'));
});

Comment: can you past your html in your question... See it will work http://jsfiddle.net/3TDQd/ Check this fiddle.

Comment: sorry the site wont allow me to edit it in html..i have added it in my original question..

Comment: You can just paste your html in the question. once you add it select the html and press ctrl k

Comment: mmmm... but it did not solve my problem i meant the ctrl+k work.. :-|

Comment: Nope..as i told i have put a console.log to make sure the value is set (the code is in my original question as 'NEW CODE') but the textfield disappears..

Comment: If you can try to replicate it in a Fiddle. I will see what the isue is otherwose no idea what is happening..

Comment: ok friend..i wll try it in Fiddle and post a comment...thanks for the help..:)